# Aptana Studio 3 Mark Occurrences button

Tags: aptana3

I know that you can go window -> preferences -> aptana studio -> [language] -> "mark occurrences with background color" checkbox.

But there used to be (in an earlier version I'm pretty sure, but definitely in vanilla Eclipse) a toolbar button to enable/disable this for all editors.

Anyone know how to get that button back? This is a feature I like to toggle on/off frequently.

Answer (score 1):

This button is available as late as Aptana Studio 3 (3.3.2.201302081546) - perhaps you are using a Perspective that does not include it? Web has it, Debug does not...

You can customize your perspective so that it shows this button under `Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective`, under `Tool Bar Visibility` the '**Mark Occurrences**' menu item is under `Editor Presentation`